# Virtualbox guest cannot access internet when host uses wireless usb adapter

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, virtualbox, internet

I'm running Windows XP SP1 as the guest OS with a bridged network adapter. It is using DHCP, and can't connect to the network/internet.

Info:
The two options for my network card in the network settings page are
`Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit network connection` and `Realtek RTL8811AU Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB 2.0 network adapter`. Neither of these will let the guest connect to the network.

The Windows XP machine was able to connect to the internet until I a) installed a wifi extender in my apartment and b) used the aforementioned wifi adapter to connect to the network. I don't think **a** is as important as **b**, but I wanted to provide the full picture.

Comment: If you remove the extender. Is this outdated insecure Windows XP machine able to connect to your network?  What revisions of the 802.11 is your access point compatible with

Comment: Why is this tagged as VirtualBox?

Comment: VirtualBox is the virtualization software I'm using

Comment: You made no mention of VirtualBox in your question.

Comment: It's in the question header

Comment: I only read the body of the question.  I don't expect information, to exist in the title, that isn't in the body of the question.  How about sticking to answering the other questions I had for you and improving your question?